# Xamrin iOS - On list view RowSelected open view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, storyboard, viewcontroller

I am new to iOS development, I googled for my problem but most of the solutions are for Swift 3. I am developing my application in Xamarin Native iOS.

I have a UITableView having a list of data. All I need to do is when ever I click a row, the event will open a new page through ViewController which will display detailed information of the selected data.

Here is my code for UITableView in PlayersListController.cs file:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad() {
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // THIS data GOES TO "PlayersListTableSource" CLASSS
    string[] data = new string[] {
        "Player One",
        "Player Two",
        "Player Three",
        "Player Four",
        "Player Five"
    };


    UITableView myTable;

    myTable = new UITableView
    {
        Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 30, View.Bounds.Width, View.Bounds.Height),
        Source = new PlayersListTableSource(data)
    };

    View.AddSubview(myTable);
}
```

Here is my model class PlayersListTableSource.cspublic class

```
PlayersListTableSource : UITableViewSource
{
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
// WHAT TO DO HERE…

new UIAlertView("Alert", "You touched: " + tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "Ok", null).Show();

tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);

// PlayerDetailController is my view controller I want to open on button click

// SOME THING LIKE THIS

PlayerDetailController PlayerDetailController = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("PlayerDetailController") as PlayerDetailController;

this.NavigationController.PushViewController(PlayerDetailController, true);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UITableViewSource won't usually have a pointer to the navigation controller, so in most instances it's necessary to provide that. The following code is a very basic way of doing what you want.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad() 
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // THIS data GOES TO "PlayersListTableSource" CLASSS
    string[] data = new string[] {
        "Player One",
        "Player Two",
        "Player Three",
        "Player Four",
        "Player Five"
    };


    UITableView myTable;

    myTable = new UITableView
    {
        Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 30, View.Bounds.Width, View.Bounds.Height),
        Source = new PlayersListTableSource(data, this.NavigationController)
    };

    View.AddSubview(myTable);
}
```

and then in your source you just want to keep hold of that navigation controller pointer for use on row select.

```
PlayersListTableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    private UINavigationController primNav {get; set;}


    public PlayersListTableSource(List<Object> myData, UINavigationController nav)
    {
        //DO what you want with your data

        primNav = nav;
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        new UIAlertView("Alert", "You touched: " + tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "Ok", null).Show();

        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);

        // PlayerDetailController is my view controller I want to open on button click

        // SOME THING LIKE THIS

        PlayerDetailController PlayerDetailController = primNav.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("PlayerDetailController") as PlayerDetailController;

        primNav.PushViewController(PlayerDetailController, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your code. On the following line:
`PlayerDetailController PlayerDetailController = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("PlayerDetailController") as PlayerDetailController;`
I am getting error "Does not contain a defination for storyboard and no extension method.."

Comment: @zainSMJ apologies, it should be primNav.Storyboard I've changed the above code to reflect this.

Comment: Works Perfectly :) Thanx